# WooCommerce Order overview add column with ordered products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to improve WooCommerce's Order overview screen, I would like to add an column with ordered products.

So I can see for example this columns:
Order #, Order Total, Ordered products, Address, Notes, Action

We have already found some code on the internet to add an column with products, but it is missing products SKU. What I can see currently:

- 1x ProductnameA
- 3x ProductnameC

What I would like to see:

- 1x ARM-002 (ProductnameA)
- 3x ARM-008 (ProductnameC)

I have used this code for adding the column:

```
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_ordered_products_column', 11);    
function add_ordered_products_column($columns) {
    $columns['order_products'] = "Ordered products";
    return $columns;
}
```

And this one for adding the content of the column:

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'add_ordered_products_column_content', 11, 2 );
function add_ordered_products_column_content( $column ) {
 global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;

    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'order_products' :

        $terms = $the_order->get_items();

        if ( is_array( $terms ) ) {
             foreach($terms as $term) {
                echo $term['item_meta']['_qty'][0] .' x '. $term['name'] .'<br />';
            }
        }

        else {
                _e( 'Unable to get products', 'woocommerce' );
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

I would like to use something like $term['sku'], but that doesn't work, neither get_sku();.
Anyone who knows a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you're looking for products SKU, replace this line of code:

```
echo $term['item_meta']['_qty'][0] .' x '. $term['name'] .'<br />';
```

with this:

```
$sku = ( $sku = get_post_meta( $term['product_id'], '_sku', true ) ) ? $sku : '';
echo $term['quantity'] . ' ' . $sku . ' x ' . $term['name'] .'<br />';
```

If after that something is still wrong, I recommend you to check [this code](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/columns.html#purchased_products_column) which works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with something like

```
<?php echo ( $sku = $_product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : __( 'n/a', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
```

Where

```
<?php 
     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
         $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
         if( necessary conditionals goes here){ ... }        
     }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please note as of Woocommerce 3.0 that this line of code:

```
echo $term['item_meta']['_qty'][0] .' x '. $term['name'] .'<br />';
```

no longer displays the qty of the item ordered.

You have to exchange that for this line of code if you're on Woocommerce 3.0 and higher:

```
echo $term['quantity'] .' x '. $term['name'] .'<br />';
```